# When trying Widget of flutter, NoSuchMethodError was thrown saying The method '_debugTypesAreRight' was called on null

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I am trying a simple flutter dart program. I am referring [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S59b-XFsyY8) tutorial, how can I solve this issue?

Getting following exception

```
I/flutter ( 4785): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4785): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown attaching to the render tree:
I/flutter ( 4785): The method '_debugTypesAreRight' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4785): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 4785): Tried calling: _debugTypesAreRight(Instance of 'RealWorldApp')
```

code is :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new RealWorldApp());

class RealWorldApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RealWorldState createState() => new RealWorldState();

}
 class RealWorldState extends State<RealWorldApp>
  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("First App"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ),
  );
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an internal error and not something wrong with your code. Try the following:

```sh
flutter upgrade &&           # use latest version
flutter packages get &&      # pub_get all packages
flutter clean &&             # delete caches
flutter build                # rebuild
```